# Power a circuit with with 12V barrel jack and USB 5V

Tags: power-supply, usb, circuit-protection, load, dual-supply

What if I use a Schottky diode at both the power rails in forward voltage mode and connect both the supplies? Will it damage my circuitry?

Reverse current will not damage my device because of the Schottky diode, but will forward current cause damage to my load?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your schematic should work but I would add one more level of protection. You can look at the common Arduinos which use the same type of circuitry. Some knock-off arduinos have a pair of pads and a tiny copper trace that can be cut and the user has to add the diode to allow 12VDC or 5vusb operation. Some arduinos have the diode in place when you buy it.   But, you have the concept correct.

Comment: If i use both the Power supply and USB at the same time. Will the their be any issue then?

Comment: With the existing diode D2 and the new diode you added in red from the USB, you shouldn't have a problem. It is the right way to do this.